# How to prevent password popup everytime for changing network configuration in OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: networking, passwords, script, prompt, osx-mountain-lion

I have a few network scripts that I used under OS X Lion that automatically created a ssh connection and then changed network configuration on my local machine to run traffic through the ssh tunnel.  I changed the network configuration using these shell commands:

```
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost ####

networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate "Wi-Fi" on
```

Now, under Mountain Lion, it asks for a password for both every time I run the script, which is very annoying.  Is there a way to have it remember the password, or bypass it, or just put it in the first time and have it remember?

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a "non-hacked" solution. For example, I would rather NOT write an applescript to type in the password for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is the right way to do it from a security viewpoint, but it works:

1)  Copy networksetup in /usr/sbin/ to another file (this way, all the other services using it will continue to require the password when run):

```
sudo cp /usr/sbin/networksetup /usr/sbin/NewNetConfig
```

2)  Add this line in your sudoers file to skip password when calling NewNetConfig:

```
username   ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/NewNetConfig
```

3)  Restart.  Then use this to change your network configuration and it shouldn't ask for a password:

```
sudo NewNetConfig -setsocksfirewallproxy "Wi-Fi" localhost ####
```

Comment: Just to be clear and thorough, to perform step 2 you need to `$ sudo visudo`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your scripts have the right permissions and owner. It should be root:wheel like this(wifi is the script name):

```
lion:~/Downloads napcae$ ls /usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root      wheel       739 25 Nov 18:35 wifi
```

You can achieve this by typing

```
lion:~/Downloads napcae$ sudo chown root:wheel wifi
```

Now you can sudo your commands in the script, i.e.

```
sudo networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled "Huawei Modem" on;
```

The Terminal/Finder should stop asking for the password. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, instead I Used a service to switch the proxy state by pressing a shortcut key.

After you've done coping networksetup to NewNetConfig and editing /etc/sudoers,
Create a new Service in Automator named "ChangeWiFiProxy". Add a Shell Script and add this script:

```
STATUS=`NewNetConfig -getsocksfirewallproxy Wi-Fi | grep -c 'Enabled: Y'`
if   [ "$STATUS" == "0" ] ; then
    sudo NewNetConfig -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi on
say on
else
    sudo NewNetConfig -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi off
    say off
fi
```

Then assign it a shortcut like Cmd + Option + ";" in "System Prefrences > Keyboard > Keyborad Shortcuts > Services".

Answer (score 0):

You can set permission `suid` to `/usr/sbin/networksetup` and then networksetup will run with root permission, so you don't need to input password anymore.

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/networksetup
```

About suid: http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html